# Run a Hive transform script on subsets of a table

Tags: hive, subset, distribute

I've got a transform script (written in R), which I'd like to run on subsets of a table. I.e. I'd like many reduce steps to run, one for each value of some column.

Assuming the original table has columns {C1, C2, C3}, the transform should run on different values of C1 and be passed C2 and C3 as input data, taking the output together with the value of C1 as the result.

I'm looking at the Hive DISTRIBUTE operation to solve this, but can't figure out the right syntax/mechanics of it.

For example, if this is my table:

```
C1,C2
a,1
a,2
b,1
b,2
b,3
```

And my script returns the mean value of C2 for each subset of the table, C1, then the result should be:

```
C1,D1
a,1.5
b,2
```

Here's the **syntactically wrong** pseudo-code for what I'd like to do. Assuming my_table has columns C1, C2:

```
from my_table
select
  C1,
  transform(
    C2
  )
using 'my_script.R'
distribute by C1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is a reduce script without a map component. You should use an identity mapper (/bin/cat) and then feed the input to the reduce part. Between the map and the reduce is the shuffle phase, that will take care of your `DISTRIBUTE BY C1` clause.
Here is something quick that I wrote, haven't gotten a chance to verify it:

```
FROM (
  FROM my_table
  MAP C1, C2
  USING '/bin/cat'
  AS C1, C2
  DISTRIBUTE BY C1 ) map_output
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mean_table
  REDUCE map_output.C1, C2
  USING 'my_script.R'
 AS C1, mean;
```

Don't forget that it's guaranteed that all records with the same value of the key (C1, in your case) go to the same reducer (i.e. the same instantiation of the script). However, you could have other records with a different value of key in the input set to the same reducer as well.

For example, you can have all of
a,1
a,2
b,1
b,2
b,3
go to the same reduce script. So, you will need ensure that you break the input set of records in your reducer

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm not sure this solves the problem, since this does not imply that my script will run on only subsets of the data. I'll still need to explicitly handle running it on 'a' rows vs. 'b' rows. I.e. if my script just computes a running mean, it will fail.